# I want to use php function in SQL query,

Tags: php, sql

I want to use str_replace() in SQL query,

```
db_query('SELECT * FROM {node} n INNER JOIN {accesslog} a ON n.nid = str_replace("node/", "", a.path);
```

but still not work. please help.

thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pick a function that the SQL engine *does* know, such as [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_replace).

Comment: INNER JOIN {accesslog} a ON n.nid = REPLACE(a.path, "node/", "")
do work! thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use MySQL's [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function instead of PHP's `str_replace`.

Comment: INNER JOIN {accesslog} a ON n.nid = REPLACE(a.path, "node/", "") do work! thank you!